# How to convert JavaScript object containing json string

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am having problem parsing JSON string into JS object .Please tell how to convert JavaScript object :

```
Object {d: "[{"worker_id":1,"worker_name":"Shivank"}]"}
```

***into***

```
Object { d: [{ "worker_id": 1, "worker_name": "Shivank" }] }
```

I have tried using

```
JSON.parse(data)
```

and

```
var dataFinal = JSON.stringify(data);
var d1 = eval('(' +dataFinal+ ')');
```

Comment: What have  you tried?

Comment: I have edited the question Please have a look at it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an object where one property value contains JSON so you only need to convert that value

Try

```
data.d= JSON.parse(data.d);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `data` is as below, which `d` is having `stringified` json data

```
var data = {d: "[{\"worker_id\":1,\"worker_name\":\"Shivank\"}]"}

console.log(data);
```

You can parse JSON and assign to `d` key

```
data.d = JSON.parse(data.d)

console.log(data); // required output
```